An operation preserving denormalized Lorenzian property
Let $f(x_0,\cdots,x_n)$ be a denormalized Lorenzian polynomial. Define $g(t,q)$ to be $f(q^n,tq^{n-1},t^2q^{n-2},\cdots,t^n)$. Is $g(t,q)$ still a denormalized Lorenzian polynomial? I check some examples and havn't found counter-examples so far.
I am mainly working on topology, so I don't know too much about Huh's theories. If you use some well-known facts in combinatorics, could you also give me some references?
